# Receive Output of Sybase ASE on the client

Tags: java, sybase

I'm trying to undersstand how I can receive the Sybase output on the client, so that I can trace the stored procedures that were additioned with several prints. Just to give a more clear need,
I have done
create procedure pippo
begin
print 'Hello wolrd'
end

and on the client side, connecting using java, I'd like to execute the query that somehow gives me the output of the print.
I know that this is possible, as dbeaver is doing it, I can obtain the output of a querz and the output of the console; that would be very appreciated.
Please let me know